# Store encrypted texts in the database , query and decrypt it back base on password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to store an encrypted text in my database, but I have no idea how to decrypted it back. I've tried

```
$salt   = 'c0d4#';
$pepper ='nsa-cia-fbi'; // secret text

$pwd_peppered = hash_hmac("sha256", $salt, $pepper);
$pwd_hashed = password_hash($pwd_peppered, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID);

echo($pwd_hashed);

// right password hash 
$pwd_hashed = '$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$QnVpT1Rqay5WSmIvRW1HZg$rgx+DWPl5bvjwlr7plnOjnE1Sf8lim01pwb6lHGzEaU';

//wrong password hash : for testing purposes 
$pwd_hashed_wrong = '$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$QnVpT1Rqay5WSmIvRW1HZg$rgx+DWPl5bvjwlr7plnOjnE1Sf8lim01pwb6lHGzEaU-wrong-!!';

if (password_verify($pwd_peppered, $pwd_hashed)) {
    echo "Password matches.";

   // I am inside this block of codes, but ... 
   // no idea how to decrypt and get my text back ... 



}
else {
    echo "Password incorrect.";
}
```

Comment: Encryption is not the same as Hashing. You can store an encrypted token in your database just fine, and decrypt it on retrieval from database, but if you hash something, you cannot unhash it.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Use a [JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt), they are signed using a key so you can ensure the integrity of the data.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for the explaination. What is the best encryption do you recommend?

Comment: @Jaquarh I am trying to build a login API, just need to store decrypted texts in db ..

Comment: Yes, and as stated in such [RFC6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749) JTW's should be used.

Comment: Which text exactly are you trying to retrieve? All you've shown us some password hashing.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption. Laravel has this built in. When you want to store an encrypted token, you'd set it like `Crypt::encryptString($plainTextToken)`, and after retrieval, you'd decrypt via `Crypt::decryptString($encryptedToken);`. Sidenote, if you use this on `password`, you're opening yourself up to serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Since this is a Laravel application, why not just use Passport or Sanctum depending on what your API needs to do?

Comment: I don't use this for passwords. no way... thanks for extra precaution

Comment: Excellent  I figured that was the case from the various comments, but you never know. This question is asked a lot, like "How do I decrypt passwords?", and it (rightfully so) tends to get closed quite quickly. Cheers!

Comment: If you're trying to retrieve the password then don't, you don't ever retrieve a password. You can only verify it, or change it

Comment: @TimLewis The only problem left is I am on Laravel 5.8.

Comment: That particular code hasn't changed much from Laravel 5.8 > 8.x: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption

Comment: I figured that as well, I tried it, and works great on 5.8.... I'm still curious if I can potentially tie the encryption to the SALT from the .env ... Do you know any possible way to do that ? so it is not decryptable without the password.

Comment: I think I can just do `base64(Crypt::encryptString('nsa-cia-fbi').'-'.$salt)`. :D  What do you think ?

Comment: Encryption in Laravel should already use the `.env` settings for Encrypt/Decrypt. See `config/app.php` for `Encryption Key` settings. It still sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel here 

Comment: Let me look into that. Thanks for answering my questions and get me going. 

Comment: You're welcome 

Comment: Stop trying to append salts to your plaintext, that's a hashing thing. [IMO peppers are universally useless, but that's a whole other argument] A decent cipher will use an Initialization Vector [IV], and a decent crypto library [eg: laravel's, hopefully] will handle that transparently to you.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot decrypt a hashed text, if you want to make a password verification  you have to hash the  password entered by the user and test it with the hash of the real password (see if the 2 hash are equaled or not )

Comment: I need to be able to decrypt it, otherwise, I can not use it. Imagine it is a token. I just don't want to store token in the database as plain text, and was trying to add a layer of cryptographic. That is my main goal.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. You **can** decrypt encrypted text, but you **cannot** unhash hashed text. Your answer is right, but you've got it worded slightly wrong.

Comment: yes but in your code you are using a hashing function " sha256 "

Comment: and a hashing function is a one way function , you can hash text with sha256 (like you have did ) but since SHA256 is a hashing function, not an encryption function, u cannot decrypt it

Answer (score 1):

there is two concepts, **hash** and **encrypt**. when you hash a string, you can not turn it back to the original string. passwords **must** be hashed and then you are allowed to store them.
If you encrypt a string you can turn result back to original string.
In laravel you can use **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt** class.
there is an example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a secret message for the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function storeSecret(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->fill([
            'secret' => encrypt($request->secret)
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.');

$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

as mentioned in [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption) documentation by [laravel](https://laravel.com/).